# Open the file in universal-newline mode using the CSV Django module

Tags: django, macos, csv, newline, python-2.x

I am trying to access a `model.filefield` in Django to parse a [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file in Python using the `csv` module. It's working on Windows, but on Mac it gave me this:

```
Exception Type: Error

Exception Value: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?
```

This is the code:

```
myfile = customerbulk.objects.all()[0].fileup

mydata = csv.reader(myfile)
    for email,mobile,name,civilid in mydata:
        print email,mobile,name,civilid
```

Comment: what is this `customerbulk.objects.all()[0].fileup` thing.  Is it a filename on a model?

Comment: fileup = models.FileField(verbose_name="CsvFile",upload_to='ExcelFiles')

if i make a small query like customerbulk.objects.get(pk=1)

Comment: The exact reason of using `rU` (It's related to the open() function and is not csv specific.): `In addition to the standard fopen() values mode may be 'U' or 'rU'. Python is usually built with universal newlines support; supplying 'U' opens the file as a text file, but lines may be terminated by any of the following: the Unix end-of-line convention '\n', the Macintosh convention '\r', or the Windows convention '\r\n'.`

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

Comment: In Python >= 3, use `newline=''` instead of `mode='U'`.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

I finally found the solution:

```
mypath = customerbulk.objects.get(pk=1).fileup.path
o = open(mypath,'rU')
mydata = csv.reader(o)
```

Comment: I believe you can simplify this. It seems odd to seek to the start after just opening the file. The following helped me overcome the same issue from an Excel spreadsheet export to CSV using the defaults:                                                             data = csv.reader(open(FILENAME, 'rU'), quotechar='"', delimiter = ',')

Comment: Yes, there's no need to seek to beginning of file just after opening. The >>>o = open(mypath, 'rU') bit, with the 'rU' flag is the important magic that worked in my case.

Comment: [PEP278](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/) explained what `rU` stands for:`In a Python with universal newline support open() the mode
    parameter can also be "U", meaning "open for input as a text file
    with universal newline interpretation".  Mode "rU" is also allowed,
    for symmetry with "rb".`

Comment: @Xiao +1 for linking to the original PEP which explains the rationale.

Comment: In Python >= 3, use `newline` instead, the default is `newline=None` which is like `newline=''` except it also translates the newlines to `\n`. I'm unsure which of these is equivalent to `mode='U'`