# Extract csv file specific columns to list in Python

Tags: python, csv, numpy, matplotlib

What I'm trying to do is plot the latitude and longitude values of specific storms on a map using matplotlib,basemap,python, etc. My problem is that I'm trying to extract the latitude, longitude, and name of the storms on map but I keep getting errors between lines 41-44 where I try to extract the columns into the list.

Here is what the file looks like:

```
1957,AUDREY,HU, 21.6N, 93.3W
1957,AUDREY,HU,22.0N,  93.4W
1957,AUDREY,HU,22.6N,  93.5W
1957,AUDREY,HU,23.2N,  93.6W
```

I want the list to look like the following:

```
latitude = [21.6N,22.0N,23.4N]
longitude = [93.3W, 93.5W,93.8W]
name = ["Audrey","Audrey"]
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
data = np.loadtxt('louisianastormb.csv',dtype=np.str,delimiter=',',skiprows=1)
'''print data'''

data = np.loadtxt('louisianastormb.csv',dtype=np.str,delimiter=',',skiprows=0)

f= open('louisianastormb.csv', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
header = reader.next()
zipped = zip(*reader)

latitude = zipped[3]
longitude = zipped[4]
names = zipped[1]
x, y = m(longitude, latitude)
```

Here's the last error message/traceback I received:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/darealmzd/lstorms.py", line 42, in
>
> header = reader.next()
> _csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?

Comment: I think the problem is in your csv files not your code. Your code runs as expected with the provided sample csv input. This post may provided some insight. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726953/open-the-file-in-universal-newline-mode-using-csv-module-django

Answer (score 76, accepted):

This looks like a problem with line endings in your code. If you're going to be using all these other scientific packages, you may as well use [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) for the CSV reading part, which is both more robust and more useful than just the `csv` module:

```
import pandas
colnames = ['year', 'name', 'city', 'latitude', 'longitude']
data = pandas.read_csv('test.csv', names=colnames)
```

If you want your lists as in the question, you can now do:

```
names = data.name.tolist()
latitude = data.latitude.tolist()
longitude = data.longitude.tolist()
```

Comment: this is great. thanks, i hadn't heard of pandas before. one small thing, if you run this on columns with different lengths, the shorter columns will populate with `null`s to match the longest column. you know a fix for this?

Comment: I'm not sure how you would have columns with different lengths in the CSV? But you can get rid of the na values with [`data.dropna()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

Comment: yeah it's a bit of a hack i'm doing for a small script. thanks =]

Comment: @chthonicdaemon I tried using your code for a similar example, however I think pands doesn't find my file, so it gives me the error " File text.csv does not exist"  where instead of text there is the name of my file. Should I add the path of the file? How do I do that?

Comment: @Euler_Salter I think that warrants a new question rather than a comment on an old one.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon  My CSV file has first row as headings. This method also reads the columns headings in the list. How to avoid reading columns headings into the list. I just want to read the values, so how do I avoid reading first row??

Comment: @Boy You would just not supply the `names=colnames` part.

Answer (score 54):

#### A standard-lib version (no pandas)

This assumes that the first row of the csv is the headers

```
import csv

# open the file in universal line ending mode 
with open('test.csv', 'rU') as infile:
  # read the file as a dictionary for each row ({header : value})
  reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
  data = {}
  for row in reader:
    for header, value in row.items():
      try:
        data[header].append(value)
      except KeyError:
        data[header] = [value]

# extract the variables you want
names = data['name']
latitude = data['latitude']
longitude = data['longitude']
```

Comment: Instead of the `try/except`, you could just use `data.setdefault(header, list()).append(value)`. That will create an empty list the first time you access the key.

Comment: `try/except` is faster, however, in case the file is large.

Comment: I get:     for header, value in row.items():
                                    ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
from sys import argv

d = open("mydata.csv", "r")

db = []

for line in csv.reader(d):
    db.append(line)

# the rest of your code with 'db' filled with your list of lists as rows and columbs of your csv file.
```