# "Transpose" an array after loads a json file in python?

Tags: python

I have a data.csv file contain 1 column call data trend in json type, each row of it is:

```
 1. [{"period":"11/2020", "UNTPRICE": 49940000,"DIST_UNTPRICE": 30789500},
     {"period":"12/2020", "UNTPRICE": 48710000,"DIST_UNTPRICE": 30719773}]
 2. [{"period":"12/2020", "UNTPRICE": 28540000,"DIST_UNTPRICE": 27428824}]
 3. [{"period":"12/2020", "UNTPRICE": 27428824,"DIST_UNTPRICE": 28540000}]
```

The question here is how to covert this column to a array like this in python

```
|UNTPRICE(11/2020)|DIST_UNTPRICE(11/2020)|UNTPRICE(12/2020)|DIST_UNTPRICE(12/2020)|
|-----------------|----------------------|-----------------|----------------------|
|     4994000     |        30789500      | 48710000        | 30719773             |
|     NULL        |        NULL          |28540000         |27428824              |
|     NULL        |        NULL          |27428824         |28540000              |
```

sample raw image of csv file
[image]

Comment: Does it really have the numbers 1, 2, 3 in the csv? Please just post the raw contents of the csv.

Comment: Are you using pandas? It has a `pivot` function.

Comment: @Barmar can you explain in more detail

Comment: @bremen_matt i just edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, write a function to convert a row from the csv file to a row in the data frame:

```py
import json

def csv_row_to_df_row(csv_row):
    csv_row = json.loads(csv_row)
    df_row = {}
    for entry in csv_row:
        period = entry['period']
        for k, v in entry.items():
            if k != 'period':
                df_row[f'{k}({period})'] = int(v)
    return df_row
```

then you can iterate all the lines in the file and add the rows to you data frame.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
with open('yourfile.csv') as f:
    for csv_row in f:
        df_row = csv_row_to_df_row(csv_row)
        df = df.append(df_row, ignore_index=True)
```

to get the same order of columns as in the desired output:

```py
df = df[['UNTPRICE(11/2020)', 'DIST_UNTPRICE(11/2020)', 'UNTPRICE(12/2020)', 'DIST_UNTPRICE(12/2020)']]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the output is not the same format that I wanted, it not contain NULL value in it

Comment: @Al3xSund3r When appending using [`pandas.DataFrame.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) `NaN` is automatically added.

Comment: I want this added as new column, append not work in this case

Comment: @Al3xSund3r I've edited the answer, does it work now?

Comment: for example my csv file contain 5 column and json string in column 3, how can I do this

Comment: @Al3xSund3r That's a seperate question. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19487003/14160477).

Comment: thanks alot for the great answer. My problem has been solve

Answer (score 0):

first load `json` using `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('data.json')
```

then transpose `dataframe` using:

```
df.T
```